# Conditional default value in Rails (Mongoid) model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

This may seem like an oxymoron, a "conditional default," but I was wondering if there is a way I can easily handle setting a default value for a field only in the case where the object is not of a certain type.

For instance, I have

```
field :object_type, type: String
field :price, type: Float, default: 0
validates :price, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
```

It would be sweet if I could add a condition such as `unless: ->{ object_type == "a"}` and take care of this inline. Will rails allow that or do I have to now set this conditional default with a `before_create` callback?

**Pseudo code for what I want to happen:**

- if the object_type is any other type than "a" then I want to set the default value for price to zero.
- if the object type is a, I want only zero and non-negative numeric values to be acceptable

Comment: what's the gem you are using?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I'm using Mongoid. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: Yes that's what I asked

Comment: I guess the other way I could phrase the question is, is there a way I can get a conditional validation to run before I set defaults? I could move this logic where I require a price for this certain type that I do not want defaulted to zero to my create action in the controller.  Though I am not sure if that's a better or worse way to organize my code.

Comment: can you add a pseudo code of what line you want to execute or skip via the conditin check ?

Comment: just added it to the question. I'm also now thinking maybe I could pass in a proc statement to the default? Going to try that.

Comment: you got it working ?

Comment: ah, not yet, so I have `field :price, type: Float, default: proc{ |object_type| 0 unless object_type == "A" }` but that keeps allowing creation of the object with a nil value for price.

Comment: You can'r have both mate, as you said *I want only zero and non-negative numeric values to be acceptable*

Comment: Ahh, @ArupRakshit I found a stupid mistake - I was using `validate` instead of `validates` so the validation never ran. Thanks for your help and sorry this was kind of a dud of a question. Going to write up my solutions below so others might be able to find this helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `proc` was the way to go here

```
field :object_type, type: String
field :price, type: Float, default: proc { object_type== "a" ?  nil : 0}
validates :price, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
```